# Map markers are not shown when ammap.js and amchart.js is used on same page

Tags: amcharts, ammap

I am trying to create dashboard using AmChart, as they are easy to work and are more interactive. I've found almost everything via example or multiple forms. I stuck at one place which is quite unusual and unable to find any particular clue why this thing happen, due to that i need opinion so here is my problem, looking forward for the quick answer from you people. Thanks in advance.

I am using Map (with markers) and Bar chart on same page due to that i need to use ammap.js (used for map) and amchart.js (user for rest of the charts) on the same page. Unfortunately when both javascripts are used map markers are not shown although rest of the things are working fine. I've try to remove only amchart.js after that markers are easily visible but bar chart is gone. Why this problem occurs, i need to make markers clickable and on the bar chart will update itself. Kindly help me out to achieve this particular task.

Thanks

Comment: please provide us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including `ammap.js` and `amcharts.js` together will cause the libraries to conflict with each other as the underlying classes contain the same methods and one will override the other. You need to include `ammap_amcharts_extension.js` instead of `ammap.js`, which will safely extend `amcharts.js` to support map functionality.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/ammap_amcharts_extension.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, you are life saver for me. Thanks again